# How can I Convert *.so(Dynamic Linkable Library) to *.a( Statically-linked library)

Tags: c, gcc

Suppose I have a `libutils.so`, but my source code has lost.   How can I convert the `libutils.so`(Dynamic Linkable Library) to `libutils.a`(Statically-linked library).

Comment: In short: you cannot.

Comment: I guess it's possible in principle, but it's non-trivial, and I'm not aware of any existing tools or combinations of tools for doing that job.